Concerning union and intersection of some subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Question: Is the following claim true or false?
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac1n,2-\frac1n\right)\subseteq\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac1n,2+\frac1n\right)$$


Is the union on the left equal to $[1,2]$ or $(1,2)$? I think $(1,2)$, which can be shown by two-sided inclusion. Each of $1$ and $2$ does not belong to the infinite union.

Is the intersection on the right equal to $[1,2]$ or $(1,2)$? I think $[1,2]$ since $1$ and $2$ belong to each set in the intersection.


So the answer is positive.
The question could be more interesting if $\subseteq$ were replaced by $\subsetneq$, but the answer to the new question is also positive.
Am I right?
Edit: I am not sure about one direction in $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n},2+\frac{1}{n})=[1,2]$:
It is clear that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n},2+\frac{1}{n}) \supseteq [1,2]$, since $x \in [1,2]$ satisfies $1-\frac{1}{n} < 1 \leq x \leq 2 < 2+\frac{1}{n}$, hence $x \in (1-\frac{1}{n},2+\frac{1}{n})$, for all $n \geq 1$.
What about the other direction $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n},2+\frac{1}{n}) \subseteq [1,2]$? I have some 'limit argument' in mind, but not sure why should it work.
However, for the question this other direction is not needed, since
the union on the left equal to $(1,2) \subset [1,2] \subseteq \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n},2+\frac{1}{n})$.
Any help is welcome, thank you.

I think you’re right

@J.W.Tanner, thank you.

I’m voting to close this question because you asked for "solution-verification". Tag-description "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplicate questions. " Your question does not satisfy this requirement.

@PaulFrost, thank you for the clarification, I apologize. Hopefully, my edit will clarify which step in the proof is in doubt.

@user237522 I retracted my close vote.

@PaulFrost, thank you very much.
